# Тесты по JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, тесты по Javascript, пригодные для подготовки к собеседованию за один день.

Comment: Думаю, на собеседовании тестов не будет, будут вопросы, и явно не про синтаксис, выход 1: прочитать пару книжек )) за сегодня. )

Answer (score 3):

**UPD**. Как вариант, можно почитать эти материалы с Хабра:

[JavaScript. Вопросы на собеседовании](http://habrahabr.ru/post/239065/)

[Собеседование на должность JavaScript разработчика](http://habrahabr.ru/post/231071/)

[Основные ошибки соискателя на собеседовании](http://habrahabr.ru/company/hh/blog/185184/)

[Как я искал сотрудников или Как не надо проходить собеседования](http://habrahabr.ru/post/183708/)

[Тест на крепкого JS программера](http://habrahabr.ru/post/76730/)

Comment: @MasterAlex, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Comment: @Expert, обновил ответ, выбрав наиболее интересные темы для соискателей работы на Javascript

Comment: @MasterAlex, Здорово!

Answer (score -1):

https://certification.mail.ru/tests/ - здесь есть тест достаточно сложный тест по JS (ECMAScript 5) без использования сторонних библиотек.